# Wordpress media upload error "Missing a temporary folder" on a local server

Tags: php, wordpress, directory

I am currently developping a WordPress website locally since I have much work to do before getting it uploaded. For local hosting purpose, I am using Local by Flywheel.
As I wanted to start testing pages layout, I tried to upload some media in the classic WP Media Uploader but I continuously get the error "XXXX has failed to upload: Missing a temporary folder.".

I've looked for the answer on the Internet and did found the "edit the wp-config.php technique" that's seems to be the only answer to this problem, but actually it does not work for me. Here's a view of the 'custom side' my wp-config file:
`

```
/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */

define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '\wp-content\temp');

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

A call of var_dump(get_temp_dir()) returns this:

```
[abs path]\app\public\wp-content\temp/'
```

Which seems to tell that the wp-config.php works correctly.

Often, online tutorials also say to set permission 755 on the "temp" folder, but since this folder is not on a remote server accessed via FTP, it does not seems that I can set that.
I also read to edit my "php.ini" file but I do not have this file in my local site folders.

Does someone knows what I should do ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so even though I searched through google and StackOverflow during 2 or 3 days, I just found the solution on another forum, the post was quite discreet...

So to anyone who may have the same problem as me:
Apparently this error is encountered on flywheel when you use an Apache web server instead of a nginx one. If you change to this last one in your Local config the error shouldn't show up anymore.
On the forum where I found this solution, the guy said that using nginx istead of Apache was a good thing because it is also faster.

Answer (score 0):

In File Explorer, browse any folders Wordpress needs write permissions on (wp-content, uploads etc.) and check that folder's Security tab. You may need to give Authenticated Users modify, read, write permissions. Doing this resolved it for me. Also make sure that in your php.ini a temp directory is indicated for any website needing one, and that as above, that temp folder has permissions. At the bottom of your php.ini in its own section, specify site path using:

```
[Path="C:/pathtoyoursite/]

upload_tmp_dir="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\pathtoyoursite/wp-content/temp"
```